# Java file.exists() can't find an XML file

Tags: java, xml, file, exists

I'm simply trying to find whether an XML file exists or not. I have this code:

```
File f = new File("customers/jim.xml");
File g = new File("customers/jim.txt");

  if(f.exists())
      {
          System.out.println("File f exists!");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("File f not found!");
      }

  if(g.exists())
      {
          System.out.println("File g exists!");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("File g not found!");
      }
```

The output:

```
File f not found!
File g exists!
```

The text file is found, the xml one not. Both files are in the same folder, and the spelling is indeed correct. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you mind posting the contents, i.e. file names in  `customers` directory?

Comment: You described what you think is correct, then we can hardly get anything wrong. More information needed, ls or dir result under that directory.

Comment: Whitespace in the file name? Which OS?

Comment: Also check that file suffix is not .XML

Comment: i would guess that the xml file doesnt exist, if you are using windows: does the explorer show extensions? or is there maybe an extension hidden behind the `.xml`. if you are using linux: is the character casing correct?

Comment: If you use Java 7, do yourself a favor: use [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). It is a much better API than `java.io.File`.

Comment: There's nothing special about XML files which would cause this behaviour. Your problem is something more basic - wrong name, wrong case, rogue whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks correct so a few things to check:

- Capital letters in the extension.
- Hidden extra extension (jim.xml.txt but .txt hidden)
- Do you have several customers directories? If so, your application might be looking in another one than you are expecting.

Comment: +1 - Another possibility is that the `jim.xml` entry is a broken symlink or shortcut.

Comment: Hidden extra extension (jim.xml.txt but .txt hidden)

Was the correct answer! I feel pretty silly right now. I will leave this thread here as a monument to me goofing up, and so that others may avoid making the same mistake. Feel free to lock this thread.